# Enlarge the tick mark of a checkbox

Tags: delphi, winapi, checkbox

Could a tick mark of a checkbox be enlarged? The nHeight parameter in CreateWindow call seems to have effect only on the checkbox' frame, not on the mark itself.

```
program WinAPICheckBox;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages;

function WndProc(h: hwnd; msg: UINT; wParam: wParam; lParam: lParam): LRESULT; cdecl;
var
  checked: Boolean;
  hFnt: HFONT;
  hBox: HWND;
begin
  case msg of
    WM_CREATE:
      begin
        hBox := CreateWindowW('button', 'Show Title', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or
          BS_CHECKBOX, 20, 20, 185, 35, h, HMENU(1), PCREATESTRUCTW(Pointer(lParam))
          ^.hInstance, nil);
        hFnt := CreateFontW(40, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Arial');
        SendMessage(h, WM_SETFONT, hFnt, 1);
        SendMessage(hBox, WM_SETFONT, hFnt, 1);
        CheckDlgButton(h, 1, BST_CHECKED);
      end;

    WM_COMMAND:
      begin
        checked := IsDlgButtonChecked(h, 1) > 0;
        if checked then begin
          CheckDlgButton(h, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
          SetWindowText(h, '');
        end
        else begin
          CheckDlgButton(h, 1, BST_CHECKED);
          SetWindowText(h, 'Check Box');
        end;
      end;

    WM_DESTROY:
      begin
        PostQuitMessage(0);
      end;
  end;
  Result := DefWindowProc(h, msg, wParam, lParam);
end;

var
  msg: TMsg;
  wc: TWndClassW;

begin
  FillChar(wc, SizeOf(TWndClass), 0);
  wc.lpszClassName := 'Check Box';
  wc.hInstance := hInstance;
  wc.hbrBackground := GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpfnWndProc := @WndProc;
  wc.hCursor := LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

  RegisterClassW(wc);
  CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, 'Check Box', WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW or WS_VISIBLE,
    150, 150, 230, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, nil);

  while GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) do begin
    TranslateMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: No, not with native (non themed) Windows controls. Yes, only the pane is affected (so it can be much tinier or bigger based on personal needs, like little/multiline text). Sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: Sure. This time I do not want to get things done at any cost and by any means. I am "researching".

Comment: You would have to owner-draw the checkbox yourself in order to change the appearance of the checkmark. But then the checkbox will lose the ability to track its own checked state, so you would have to track that yourself as well.

Comment: I discourage from owner-drawing - then the user might not recognize it as what it should be, it can optically behave unexpected if you don't cover every case (f.e. disabled), and as per Windows version/theme it sticks out even more with you having little to no chance to draw it as similar as the original. Have you tried [`BS_PUSHLIKE`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070921-00/?p=25023) as style? I see it almost never in use, but a switch-like button might be an alternative to you.